# jQuery $this with multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight a multiple links when one clicked. The problem is that only one link that's clicked is highlighted but not all three links.

Here is the code:

```
$('#vid_link0, #vidtop_link0, #vidmob_link0').click(function() {
  $('[id^=vid_link],[id^=vidtop_link],[id^=vidmob_link]').css('background-color','inherit');
  $(this).css('background-color','#A9CDEB');
});
```

This should make #vid_link0, #vidtop_link0, #vidmob_link0 highlighted when one of them clicked. But only the one that's clicked is highlighted. Any idea?

Comment: $(this) only refers to the element that is clicked not all of them

Comment: i'd suggest using a common class on the elements for a cleaner code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var vid_all = $('#vid_link0, #vidtop_link0, #vidmob_link0'); //cache selector
vid_all.click(function () {
    $('[id^=vid_link],[id^=vidtop_link],[id^=vidmob_link]').css('background-color', 'inherit');
    vid_all.css('background-color', '#A9CDEB'); //change color of all elements
});
```

---

[this](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) refers to the current element clicked so it changes the background-color of that element,

Comment: @SetSailMedia might be but i didn't down-voted him.

Comment: @SetSailMedia, I am not the downvoter. Do not talk non-sense

Comment: @SetSailMedia that's pretty harsh. Saptal's profile says he did not downvote an answer. You should research before flaming.

Comment: Yeah we can not blame some-body like this.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Do not assume things...

Comment: The revenge comment is a joke, jesus christ, devs are supposed to have a sense of humour

Comment: @Huangism how are we supposed to know it's a joke?

Comment: @RUJordan rampant downvoting is a joke. 1000 rep to downvote please

Comment: @Huangism It has offendended me

Comment: The world is an offensive place, you know ;) I'll save my sarcasm for other audiences.

Comment: @Satpal well stop being so serious, I thought it was a joke and I am sure a lot of others did too. You can't take a comment like that to be serious.

Comment: @Satpal you comment has more up-votes than my answer :) and i know u didn't down-voted .

Comment: @TusharGupta, Now Its good enough

Answer (score -3):

Guess nobody cares for readability anymore?

```
var links = $('#vid_link0, #vidtop_link0, #vidmob_link0')

links.click(function() {
  links.css('background-color','#A9CDEB');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLdMx/

Comment: **I am not the downvoter** but you kinda removed an important line, put a comment on readability about other answer while your answer isnt more or less readable than Tushar answer...

Comment: I disagree to an extent. true he probably has more, but he could always use an `each` loop or many other methods of adding the numeric value to it. using `ID` for this is wrong from the start. A more correct and less problematic way would be to use classes for the items that are clicked, but semantics. I believe that before you can take points off a person by downvoting, you must first acquire 100 or so. This answer technically is correct, as `$(this)` will not work with the methods he has used.

Comment: How is this answer any different than Tushar's answer?

Comment: TBH, stackoverflow is an helping center. Reputation shouldn't be considered as a score, but you should feel good if your answer helped the OP. As for the downvoter, it mean that 3 persons though your answer was incorrect or incomplete. It is in fact incomplete since you removed 1 line. You also have the exact same code as an older answer. You even said in a comment *"A more correct and less problematic way would be"* which could be in the answer to be more complete and to explain your point. Don't take downvotes personnaly, it just mean some peoples doesnt agree with your answer.

Comment: @rlemon there were other answers when I posted, now deleted, that were very messy. I have no quarrels with Tushar's approach, it's very interesting. I just wanted to express that the objects were defined outside of the click event, and modified within.

Comment: I'm moreso pointing out that your answer does not contain any additional information than the older answer from Tushar (in fact like has been pointed out you missed some stuff) - this is likely the reason people were initially downvoting you. The onslaught of downvotes was likely because you complained about them. If Meta has taught me anything it is that complaining about downvotes generally lands you a few more.

Comment: @rlemon moot, but I don't mind the downvotes, as long as they're accompanied with a reason *why* and not just a result of petty squabbles. The approach, while similar, is different. The answers were moments apart. Moving on now.